# Could not connect to localhost:10000 HUE GUI

Tags: hadoop, hive

the following issue I have.

Any suggestions how should I trace this problem?

**HIVE**
Could not connect to localhost:10000 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('Could not connect to localhost:10000',)

Should I change hue.ini? Should I check hive services? Should I check the port? I have reinstalled hadoop and hue twice already no success.

I have read a lot of similar threads but haven;t found solution + I'm newbie to linux.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution?